# How encrypt message node.js sendmail?

Tags: email, encryption, rsa, private-key, postfix-mta

I am using **sendmail** in **node.js** to send Emails. my mail server is **postfix**.
my TLS parameters in postfix config file is like this:

```
# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /home/avanel/CMS/Render/ipeccongress_com.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /home/avanel/CMS/Render/capk.txt
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.
```

BTW i used my SSL certificate and key (I mean same as https).

but when receive gmail says is not encrypted. what is wrong?

Comment: TLS is only going to encrypt the connection between endpoints. If you want an encrypted email, the contents of the message must be encrypted before it is sent.

Comment: thanks. and have You any tutoral for this?